# conflict when generating devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

i'm using Rails 3 with Devise 2.0

i'm using [this tutorial](http://railscasts.com/episodes/209-introducing-devise) `User`

the problem is :

1- the command

```
rails generate devise User
```

doesn't generate the required views and i had to run

```
rails generate devise_views
```

in order to generate the views files .. is that wrong ?

2- every thing went correctly and the routes are generated and i can show the 
sign in and sign up routes when typing rake routes but

when opening any link like

```
localhost:3000/users/sign_up
```

Rails assume that `sign_up` is the id for the user and shows this message

```
Showing /Users/wrightgd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/devise-1.1.rc0/app/views/devise/sessions/new.html.erb where line #3 raised:

wrong number of arguments (3 for 2)
```

**found answer**

i tried to "devise","2.1.2" gem and regenerated the files again it works good , even didn't  have to 
`rails generate devise_views`

Comment: could you show your rake routes file? because it seems you have a route `users/:id` that conflicts with devise.

Comment: Following what @Khaled, it seems that that you defined your `resources users` before your `devise_for` in your `routes.rb` file

Comment: te rake routes : http://pastie.org/5647570

rake routes file : http://pastie.org/5647577

Comment: @pjam no resoures user is after devise_for

Comment: it worked now thanks guys ,, Question updated